# How do I get the find module to work in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

My playbook does not create a /tmp/results.txt file, but I expect it to do so with the content of the results of the `find` module.

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Do stuff
  become: yes
  hosts: fun
  tasks:
  - name: Delete directory
    find:
      paths: /home/jdoe/subdir
      patterns: "jj*jj"
      use_regex: yes
    register: find_results
  - shell: "echo {{ item.path }} > /tmp/results.txt"
    with_items: "{{ find_results.files }}"
```

A managed node with the "fun" label has this subdirectory:
/home/jdoe/subdir/jj3jj/

What is wrong with my playbook?

Answer (score 1):

Remove *use_regex: yes*. Quoting from the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html)

> If false the patterns are file globs (shell) if true they are python regexes.

If you want to use Python regex then the pattern would be probably something like this

```
patterns: '[j]{2}.[j]{2}'
```

You probably want to append to file **>>**

```
echo {{ item.path }} >> /tmp/results.txt
```